# Problem with program installation

Tags: wpf, wcf, visual-studio-2010, installation

I have setup project in VS 2010 that i using to install wpf program with windows service. If i installed program, then in `start menu -> all programs` formed program folder with two shortcuts - start program and check for updates. And all works normal. But then i logoff and logon with another user, i try to start program from `start menu -> all programs ...shortcut`, but program instead installation starts, and i had error - `error 1001. the specified service already exists`. Herewith, if i try start .exe with `'program files'` folder then program work normal.

Comment: How did you install the program? For all users? If you have a look at the path to the program on the 2nd user, what does it show? It look's like you start the installation process, which doesn't work because the service is already installed.